# Windows wake up from sleep, when it goes sleep by script

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, sleep, power-management

I've found a script which put my computer to sleep and I did Task Scheduler which runs the sleeping script at 4am. Well, problem here is that when I put my computer to sleep manually I can wake it up by pressing any key on my wireless logitech keyboard, but I can't wake it up with my keyboard if the task scheduler / script puts my computer to sleep. So should I change some setup or script etc. to be able wake my computer if it put sleep by a script? Down below is the code I use.

```
Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bios would have to support that level of Wake/Sleep. I'm not sure what the sleep state is, but just google wake computer from bios clock and it will come up.

Log into your Bios, and see if you can enable that function.

As for triggering it, you'd have to code your script to write to the bios every time the computer sleeps - if the time changes. If static, you could set it to wake at X:XX, every day, providing your bios supports this.

Another option is Wake on Lan. You could have another computer, laptop, or even an iOS App - there are a number of Networking Apps that can send wake packets. You'd have to search the iOS / Android store for options on ones that can wake on schedules - but I am sure they are there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hibernate enabled, then that command will hibernate the computer instead of sleep.

You may disable hibernate by running in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd)
the following command :

```
powercfg -h off
```

You may put the computer to sleep when hibernate is enabled
by using the free
[PsShutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown)
and the command :

```
psshutdown.exe -d -t 0 -accepteula
```